# Setup MSSQL replication with peer to peer topology: problem setting up Conflict Detection

Tags: sql-server, replication, p2p, topology

I'm setting up a SQL Replication strategy, using MSSQL2008 with peer-to-peer publications (2 servers, each one subscribes to the other).
I followed this [HOWTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152536.aspx) from MSDN, and the setup seems to be working fine: add a record to one table on server A, query on server B shows the new record. So far, so good.
So far I only have one table 'Templates':

> *Id* PK (calculated field)
>   *NodeId* int default 1/2  (Server A = 1, Server B = 2)
>   *LocalId* int autoid
>   *Name* nvarchar(100)

Now, I would like to enable 'Conflict detection', which should be enabled by default. But every time I try to save the 'Conflict Detection' feature in the Publication Properties I get the following error:

> Cannot save Peer conflict detection properties.
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Program Location:
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand)
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationObject.ExecCommand(String commandIn)
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.TransPublication.SetPeerConflictDetection(Boolean enablePeerConflictDetection, Int32 peerOriginatorID)
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PubPropSubscriptionOptions.SaveP2PConflictDetection()
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PubPropSubscriptionOptions.SaveProperties(ExecutionMode& executionResult)
>
> **Column name 'Id' does not exist in the target table or view.**
>   Changed database context to 'TestDB'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.2531&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1911&LinkId=20476
>
> Server Name: SERVER_A
>   Error Number: 1911
>   Severity: 16
>   State: 1
>   Line Number: 2
>
> Program Location:
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)

Now, I googled the hell out of this error, and nothing shows up. I also can't seem to find out what the exact target table of the error "Column name 'Id' does not exist..." is.
Has anyone every done this successfully? Am I missing something? Having this setup without conflict detection feels pretty useless...

**EDIT**
OK, so after some more research and setting up with different databases etc, I found out that the calculated 'Id' column of the Templates table is the culprit. I don't know why, but the replication doesn't seem to allow calculated columns (which are also primary key).
It works now too, without the 'Id' column, and using the NodeId and LocalId as a combined PK.
So now the question is, why isn't it allowed to have a calculated column as PK for replication with conflict detection?